# $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function such that $f'(x)\le r<1 $ , does $f$ necessarily have a fixed point ?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function . If $\exists r \in \mathbb R $ such that $|f'(x)|\le r<1 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ then using Lagrange's theorem one can show $f$ is a Lipscitz contraction and then use Banach contraction principle to conclude $f$ has a unique fixed-point. My question is what happens if $f'(x)\le r<1 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ? Then does $f$ even have a fixed point ?

Comment: @Woria That has a fixed point at $x=0$.

Comment: If $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$, then $f(0) = 0$!

Comment: @learnmore That doesn't satisfy $f'(x)<1$.

Comment: @learnmore To answer your edit, $-x-3=x$ $\implies$ $-3=2x$ $\implies$ $x=-3/2$.

Comment: @user21820: But none of the answers $f(x)=\sqrt {x^2+1}$ ; $f(x)=\log(1+e^x)$ satisfies the $r$ condition ; for example if there existed such an $r$ for say the second function then $e^x/(1+e^x) \le r , \forall x \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} e^x/(1+e^x)=1 \le r <1$ contradiction! I don't know how that answer got accepted

Comment: @user123733: Yes I just read it and realized that if you noticed my comment there! I was about to answer this question but I see *tetori* has already done it.

Comment: @user21820: So could you mark this one not a duplicate :)

Comment: @user123733: I'm not the one! I retracted my close vote earlier already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ has no fixed point then $f(x)<x$ for all $x$ or $f(x)>x$ for all $x$. Assume that $f(x)>x$ for all $x$, then $f(x)-f(0)>x-f(0)$ for all $x>0$. Take $x=f(0)t$ for $t>0$, then 
$f(f(0)t)-f(0)>f(0)(t-1)$. Dividing $f(0)t$ both sides then
$$\frac{f(f(0)t)-f(0)}{f(0)t}\ge 1-\frac{1}{t}.$$
By mean value theorem then we can find for some $c\in (0,f(0)t)$ such that $f'(c)\ge 1-1/t$, so $f'$ cannot be bounded by $r<1$.

Similarly, you can check that $f'$ cannot be bounded by $r<1$ in the case $f(x)<x$ for all $x$.